# Custom form in backend is redirecting to /admin

Tags: magento2, admin, forms

I've created a custom form in my backend.

I can access it via /admin/export/export/index.

But when I submit my form, Magento is redirecting me to my admin home page. My form needs only to have 1 button to trigger the export of some data.

See my phtml :

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $block->getUrl('export/export/index')?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="export">
    <button type="submit">Exporter les données</button>
</form>
```

and my controler :

```
    public function execute()
{
    if('POST' == $this->getRequest()->getMethod()){ //not going inside 
        die("post"); 
        $this->_redirect('/admin/export/export/index');
    }

    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->renderLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error because all of the post requests need to have a valid `form_key` value sent.

try adding this inside your form tag.

```
<?= $block->getLayout()->getBlock('form_key');?>
```

BUt I'm not sure if that works for admin forms.

If that does not work, try this:
add this in the block that renders the form

```
private $formKey;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->formKey = $formKey;
}

public function getFormKey()
{
    return $this->formKey->getFormKey();
}
```

Now you can add this to your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?= $block->getFormKey();?>" />
```

Comment: Yes, that's it !

Comment: which one? I haven't tested any of them. The short one or the long one?

Comment: Not tested yet, but I've tried to add the key in ajax form (by getting the key thourhg the url), and the ajax is working (I'll let you know which one is working)